# Making masks based on euclidean distance with pyopencl, arrayfire or another python opencl library

Tags: python, numba, cupy, pyopencl, arrayfire

I am doing 2D or 3D binary masks around given coordinates and then identifying them as labels with scipy.ndimage.label.
Now, I have a cupy solution, a numpy solution. Cupy is fast, numpy is very slow, both do their job. I'm trying to make it run on other non nvidia GPUs or CPUs with openCl or any other form that would be more "cross platform" such as pyopencl or numba, or tensorflow even (or all of the above)

This is my current function:

```
def make_labels_links(shape,j,radius=5,_algo="GPU"):
    import scipy.ndimage as ndi

    if _algo == "GPU":
        import cupy as cp

        if 'z' in j:
            pos = cp.dstack((j.z,j.y,j.x))[0]#.astype(int)
            print("3D",j)
        else:
            pos = cp.dstack((j.y,j.x))[0]#.astype(int)
            print("2D",j)

        ndim = len(shape)
        # radius = validate_tuple(radius, ndim)
        pos = cp.atleast_2d(pos)

        # if include_edge:
        in_mask = cp.array([cp.sum(((cp.indices(shape).T - p) / radius)**2, -1) <= 1
                    for p in pos])
        # else:
        #     in_mask = [np.sum(((np.indices(shape).T - p) / radius)**2, -1) < 1
        #                for p in pos]
        mask_total = cp.any(in_mask, axis=0).T

        ##if they overlap the labels won't match the points
        #we can make np.ones * ID of the point and then np.max(axis=-1)
        labels, nb = ndi.label(cp.asnumpy(mask_total))
        
    #this is super slow
    elif _algo=='CPU':
        if 'z' in j:
            # "Need to loop each t and do one at a time"
            pos = np.dstack((j.z,j.y,j.x))[0]#.astype(int)
            print("3D",j)
        else:
            pos = np.dstack((j.y,j.x))[0]#.astype(int)
            print("2D",j)

        ndim = len(shape)
        pos = np.atleast_2d(pos)
        in_mask = np.array([np.sum(((np.indices(shape).T - p) / radius)**2, -1) <= 1
                    for p in pos])
        mask_total = np.any(in_mask, axis=0).T

        labels, nb = ndi.label(mask_total)
```

shape is for example (1024,1024) or (20,1024,1024)
j is the positions as a pandas dataframe
for example:

```
    ID  Frame   z   y   x   mass    size    ecc
0   14  0   9.121369    24.139295   297.156056  5311.661985 1.383264    NaN
1   7   0   8.270742    24.880990   308.757851  6341.082129 1.403242    NaN
2   1   0   4.881552    28.963021   291.900410  6587.918081 1.330116    NaN
3   8   0   8.015537    31.137655   304.999176  5423.140504 1.341228    NaN
4   15  0   10.910010   32.275774   298.940183  6033.069086 1.333235    NaN
5   4   0   7.057360    33.958352   313.252877  8123.989610 1.395905    NaN
6   9   0   7.922786    39.966382   308.092925  6683.742777 1.398941    NaN
7   5   0   7.163435    40.774834   329.106137  5225.643216 1.402079    NaN
8   10  0   7.665061    49.844910   306.998559  6054.428176 1.408336    NaN
9   11  0   7.909787    50.951857   320.125061  5057.551819 1.314976    NaN
10  6   0   7.148229    52.051917   312.929513  9427.345719 1.351461    NaN
11  12  0   7.599882    55.917379   303.916436  6220.891194 1.401507    NaN
12  0   0   3.992557    59.060168   298.188021  7489.421410 1.391892    NaN
13  13  0   7.684166    62.945226   303.940392  7970.470413 1.384929    NaN
14  3   0   6.102017    70.796726   316.141957  5091.926046 1.393204    NaN
15  2   0   4.937488    87.916144   192.836998  5068.320508 1.330015    NaN
```

I tried to do it with pyopencl but I was not able to implement it, any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for pyopencl

```
def make_labels_links_opencl(shape, j, radius=5):

    import numpy as np
    import pyopencl as cl
    from scipy.ndimage import label
    if 'z' in j:
        # "Need to loop each t and do one at a time"
        positions = np.dstack((j.z,j.y,j.x))[0]#.astype(int)
        print("3D",j)
    else:
        positions = np.dstack((j.y,j.x))[0]#.astype(int)
        print("2D",j)
    # Prepare data
    mask = np.zeros(shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    positions_flat = positions.flatten().astype(np.float32)
    radius = np.float32(radius)
    
#    platform = cl.get_platforms()
#    my_gpu_devices = platform[1].get_devices(device_type=cl.device_type.GPU)
#    ctx = cl.Context(devices=my_gpu_devices)

    # PyOpenCL setup
    ctx = cl.create_some_context()
    queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
    mf = cl.mem_flags

    # Create buffers
    mask_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=mask)
    positions_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=positions_flat)
    
    # Kernel code
    kernel_code = """
    __kernel void fill_mask(__global uchar *mask, __global const float *positions, const float radius, const int num_positions) {
        int x = get_global_id(0);
        int y = get_global_id(1);
        int z = get_global_id(2);
        int width = get_global_size(0);
        int height = get_global_size(1);
        int depth = get_global_size(2);
        int idx = x + y * width + z * width * height;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < num_positions; ++i) {
            float pz = positions[i * 3];
            float py = positions[i * 3 + 1];
            float px = positions[i * 3 + 2];
            
            float distance = sqrt(pow(px - x, 2) + pow(py - y, 2) + pow(pz - z, 2));
            if (distance <= radius) {
                mask[idx] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    """
    
    # Build kernel
    prg = cl.Program(ctx, kernel_code).build()
    
    # Execute kernel
    global_size = shape[::-1]  # Note: PyOpenCL uses column-major order, so we reverse the dimensions
    prg.fill_mask(queue, global_size, None, mask_buf, positions_buf, radius, np.int32(len(positions)))
    
    # Read back the results
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, mask, mask_buf)
    labels,_=label(mask)
    return labels,positions
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `for` loop with array operations. For example, in the mask computation, we can rearrange the squared sum as follows:

```
inarr = np.indices(shape).T
a = np.sum(inarr, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
a2 = np.sum(inarr ** 2, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

b = pos
for _ in range(len(shape)):
    b = np.expand_dims(b, axis=0)
b2 = b ** 2

sq_sum = a2 - a * 2 * b + b2 * len(shape)

mask_total = np.any(sq_sum <= radius ** 2, axis=-1).T
```

Comment: 117     b = np.expand_dims(b, axis=0)
118 b2 = b ** 2
--> 120 sq_sum = a2 - a * 2 * b + b2 * len(shape)
        len(shape) = 2
        shape = (513, 513)
        a = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (513, 513, 1) int64
        a2 = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (513, 513, 1) int64
        b = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1, 1, 3, 2) float64
        b2 = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (1, 1, 3, 2) float64
122 mask_total = np.any(sq_sum <= radius ** 2, axis=-1).T
123 labels, nb = ndi.label(mask_total)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (513,513,1) (1,1,3,2)

Comment: what information does `shape` contain vs what `j` contains? Is `shape` the shape of `j`? Or is there some relation between them?

Comment: j is the pandas dataframe that becomes "pos" with pos = np.dstack((j.z,j.y,j.x))  example above.
the shape is the size of the image where the points are contained. for example (1024,1024) in 2D or (17,1024,1024) for 3D.

Comment: Works, but slower than original.

def make_labels_links_alternative(shape, j, radius=5):
    if 'z' in j:
        pos = j[['z', 'y', 'x']].values
    else:
        pos = j[['y', 'x']].values

    ndim = len(shape)
    inarr = np.indices(shape).T
    a = np.sum(inarr, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    a2 = np.sum(inarr ** 2, axis=-1, keepdims=True)

    b = pos
    for _ in range(len(shape)):
        b = np.expand_dims(b, axis=-2)
    b2 = b ** 2

    sq_sum = a2 - a * 2 * b + b2 * len(shape)

    mask_total = np.any(sq_sum <= radius ** 2, axis=-1).T
    return mask_total